# How can I change the color of the value base on the amount of the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this HTML table and JS

```js
var example = document.getElementid('*Numerical Value*');
var exampledbref = firebase.database().ref().child('example').child('value');
exampledbref.on('value'
  snap => expample.innerText = snap.val());
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table width="200" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>String</td>
        <td>String</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>*Numerical Value*</td>
        <td>*Numerical Value*</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**This model works and does it needs to do which is fetch and display data on the table from firebase.**

My question,
How can I change the color of value based on the amount of the value being fetched from firebase?

For example, I am thinking of a parameter where if the value is less than `5` the color of the value itself changes to the color red. Now if it is more than `5` the color of the value is `green`.

If the data being fetched has the value of `4`, how can it change so that the value is being displayed in `red` and furthermore if its more than `5` the color of the value becomes `green`? How can I make this work?

Comment: you code isn't valid, being a programmer it is a good practice that you check the code before forwarding it.

Comment: The real code has sensitive information. I just needed a reference with a few 'dummy' examples. its not meant to be taken seriously.

Comment: whatever you need it for the reference that you are using should be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery solution to check values would be

jQuery

```
// for each <td>
$('td').each(function(){
   // get the text value in each <td>
   var val = $(this).text();
   // convert to int
   var int = parseInt(val);
   // if more than 5
   if(int > 5) {
      $(this).css({'background': 'green'});
   }else {
       $(this).css({'background': 'red'});
   }
});
```

A simple fiddle - https://fiddle.jshell.net/Jim_Miraidev/akcgabug/